# jquery check if input string length > 5 button enabled?

Tags: html, jquery

I want to achieve this kind of setup like if the user input string is greater than 5 the button submit will be enabled dynamically using jquery.

```
<input id="setup_log" type="text" name="log" class="form-control">

<button id="submit_log" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" disabled="disabled">submit</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_log').prop('disabled', true);

  function validateNextButton() {
    var buttonDisabled = $('#setup_log').val().trim() === '';
    $('#submit_log').prop('disabled', buttonDisabled);
  }
  $('#setup_log').on('keyup', validateNextButton);
});
//Not satisfied with this!
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free coding service. Show us what research you did and what attempts you made first. Thanks!

Comment: `if ($('#setup_log').val().trim().length <= 5)` - what am I missing?  You seem to have everything you need (now that you've added the missing code).

Comment: Hi, I updated my script that's the only code I've searched and did try instead === '' I did > 5 and nothing happen. thanks guys.

Comment: Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lfwt15q/)

Comment: You're missing the `if`  - `if (test) do_something`

Comment: @Zuckerberg didn't come up in my mind sir thank you for your idea.

Comment: For future reference, please read [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add an event listener on #setup_log,

```
$('#setup_log').on('keyup', function(){
    if(this.value.length > 5) $('#submit_log').attr('disabled', true);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_log').prop('disabled', true);
  function validateNextButton(a) {
    $('#submit_log').prop('disabled', $('#setup_log').val().length < 5);
  }
  $('#setup_log').on('keyup', validateNextButton);
});
```